# List Manipulation Pattern

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got several 1D lists and Transposed ones. And I constructed two functions. One of them returns X Position in the list of the Largest Y Number

```
xPosOnMaxYNumDataFull = Part[Flatten[{Max[dyDataFull], Position[dyDataFull, Max[dyDataFull]]}], 2];
```

and the second one returns X Number of the Largest Y Number

```
xNumOnMaxYNumDataFull =  Part[dxDataFull, Part[Flatten[{Max[dyDataFull], Position[dyDataFull, Max[dyDataFull]]}], 2]]
```

Can I've got 2 *fuctions* that take and replace `dxDataFull` and `dyDataFull` for any list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a function that returns the position of the max in y-list and the value in a x-list at this position. The following function takes x- and y-list and returns a list with 2 elements, the position of the max in y-list and the x-value:

```
getMaxX[xlist_, ylist_] := 
 Module[{t}, {t = Position[ylist, Max[ylist]][[1]], xlist[[t]]} // 
   Flatten]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 4, 2, 1};

b = {2, 3, 8, 4};
```

Using `PositionLargest` (new in 13.2)

```
{First[#], Extract[#] @ a} & @ PositionLargest[b]
```

{3, 2}